# create custom registration form with conatct info and comapny info Magento

Tags: magento, customization, registration

Hi friends i am not expert in **magento** but i have some good knowledge of its themng but i dont have a very good knowledge of modules , i need to **create** a

> custom registration form with contact info and company info

details ,

> i need to create this on my own custom page , i need the magento
>   default registration page also

, i have check the

```
app\code\core\Mage\Customer\controllers/AccountController
```

in which i got the

```
public function createPostAction()
    {
        $session = $this->_getSession();
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
        $session->setEscapeMessages(true); // prevent XSS injection in user input
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $errors = array();

            if (!$customer = Mage::registry('current_customer')) {
                $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setId(null);
            }

            /* @var $customerForm Mage_Customer_Model_Form */
            $customerForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
            $customerForm->setFormCode('customer_account_create')
                ->setEntity($customer);

            $customerData = $customerForm->extractData($this->getRequest());

            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed', false)) {
                $customer->setIsSubscribed(1);
            }

            /**
             * Initialize customer group id
             */
            $customer->getGroupId();

            if ($this->getRequest()->getPost('create_address')) {
                /* @var $address Mage_Customer_Model_Address */
                $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
                /* @var $addressForm Mage_Customer_Model_Form */
                $addressForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
                $addressForm->setFormCode('customer_register_address')
                    ->setEntity($address);

                $addressData    = $addressForm->extractData($this->getRequest(), 'address', false);
                $addressErrors  = $addressForm->validateData($addressData);
                if ($addressErrors === true) {
                    $address->setId(null)
                        ->setIsDefaultBilling($this->getRequest()->getParam('default_billing', false))
                        ->setIsDefaultShipping($this->getRequest()->getParam('default_shipping', false));
                    $addressForm->compactData($addressData);
                    $customer->addAddress($address);

                    $addressErrors = $address->validate();
                    if (is_array($addressErrors)) {
                        $errors = array_merge($errors, $addressErrors);
                    }
                } else {
                    $errors = array_merge($errors, $addressErrors);
                }
            }

            try {
                $customerErrors = $customerForm->validateData($customerData);
                if ($customerErrors !== true) {
                    $errors = array_merge($customerErrors, $errors);
                } else {
                    $customerForm->compactData($customerData);
                    $customer->setPassword($this->getRequest()->getPost('password'));
                    $customer->setConfirmation($this->getRequest()->getPost('confirmation'));
                    $customerErrors = $customer->validate();
                    if (is_array($customerErrors)) {
                        $errors = array_merge($customerErrors, $errors);
                    }
                }

                $validationResult = count($errors) == 0;

                if (true === $validationResult) {
                    $customer->save();

                    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_register_success',
                        array('account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer)
                    );

                    if ($customer->isConfirmationRequired()) {
                        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail(
                            'confirmation',
                            $session->getBeforeAuthUrl(),
                            Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
                        );
                        $session->addSuccess($this->__('Account confirmation is required. Please, check your email for the confirmation link. To resend the confirmation email please <a href="%s">click here</a>.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($customer->getEmail())));
                        $this->_redirectSuccess(Mage::getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure'=>true)));
                        return;
                    } else {
                        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
                        $url = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer);
                        $this->_redirectSuccess($url);
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                    if (is_array($errors)) {
                        foreach ($errors as $errorMessage) {
                            $session->addError($errorMessage);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $session->addError($this->__('Invalid customer data'));
                    }
                }
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                if ($e->getCode() === Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS) {
                    $url = Mage::getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
                    $message = $this->__('There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%s">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.', $url);
                    $session->setEscapeMessages(false);
                } else {
                    $message = $e->getMessage();
                }
                $session->addError($message);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost())
                    ->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.'));
            }
        }

        $this->_redirectError(Mage::getUrl('*/*/create', array('_secure' => true)));
    }
```

> which is for creating new account

,

> but i don't want to edit this function because i need the magento
>   default registration page als

o , **so please suggest me how can i create a new function from where i can make the customer provide there information and can register and i can store that in database , basically i need to store the contact info and company info in address tables so that the information can be shown in admin**

Comment: Something to get start: http://magerts.com/create-a-new-model-and-store-contact-details-in-database/

Answer (score 1):

**Your custom module should contain something similar:**
Package/Module/etc/config.xml
Package/Module/controllers/contactController.php
Package/Module/sql/modulename_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php
app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/customercontact.xml

**config.xml:**

```
<config>

...

<modules>
    <Package_Module>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Package_Module>
</modules>

<frontend>
<!--configure your controllers-->
<routers>
  <modulename>
     <use>standard</use>
       <args>
         <module>Package_Module</module>
         <frontName>modulename</frontName>
       </args>
  </modulename>
</routers>
<layout>
  <updates>
      <modulename>
          <file>customercontact.xml</file>
      </modulename>
  </updates>
</layout>
</frontend>

<global>
<blocks></blocks><!--you can read some blogs etc-->
<models></models><!--you can read some blogs etc-->
<helpers></helpers><!--you can read some blogs etc-->
<resources>
            <modulename_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Package_Module</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </modulename_setup>
            <modulename_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </modulename_write>
            <modulename_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </modulename_read>
        </resources>
</global>

...

</config>
```

**ContactController.php**

```
public function customerDetailsAction(){

   /*render your form 
     Use layout handle to set your own blocks
    */

}

public function customerDetailsPostAction(){

   /*borrow some logic from AccountController or Build your own
     get posted data, validate and set to model & save
    */

}
```

**mysql4-install-1.0.0.php**

Used below script in few of my similar tasks:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$setup = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup', 'core_setup');//invoke customer entity setup class

// add your attribute to customer entity
$setup->addAttribute(
        'customer', 
        'attribute_code', 
        array(
                'type'              => 'varchar',
                'input'             => 'text',
                'label'             => 'Company name',
                'global'            => 1,
                'visible'           => 1,
                'required'          => 0,
                'user_defined'      => 1,
                'visible_on_front'  => 1,

         )
);

if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.6.0', '<='))
{
      $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
      $attrSetId = $customer->getResource()->getEntityType()->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
      $setup->addAttributeToSet('customer', $attrSetId, 'General', 'attribute_code');
}
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.4.2', '>='))
{
    /*
     * To get new attribute listed for customer/form  various models, example checl line 275 to 277 AccountController.php 
     */
    Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', 'attribute_code')
    ->setData(
               'used_in_forms', 
                array(
                       'adminhtml_customer',//will make new attribute appear in admin
                       'customer_account_create',//will make new attribute appear on registration
                       'customer_account_edit',//will make new attribute appear in account dashboard
                       'checkout_register'// on checkout page
                )
    )
    ->save();
}
```

**customercontact.xml**

```
<layout>

...

<modulename_contact_customerDetails>
 <update handle="customer_account_create"/><!--if only some additional fields are needed-->
 <referene name="customer_form_register"><!--set your template based on customer/form/register.phtml-->
  <action method="setTemplate">path to your template</action>
 </reference>
</modulename_contact_customerDetails>

...

</layout>
```

Hope this gives an idea of what needed to be done !

Answer (score 0):

The seemingly easiest path ahead for you would be to create a custom module, with a frontend controller, a single table model and an admin grid if you wish to present the data collected by the contact form to the admin users in the way other magento modules show the data.

Creating magento extensions is quite easy if right set of tools are used, you can use [this](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/) module creator to create an extension quite instantly.